# Flag Non-Unique Rows (After the First Instance)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet where I am needing to create an array formula that will determine uniqueness and flag non-unique rows. I need it to flag non-unique rows but only the second & subsequent duplicates (the first duplicate will not be flagged and should say "Unique"). I have this formula but it includes the first duplicate.

```
={"Unique";
  ArrayFormula(
    IFS(
      $C$2:$C="","",
      $C$2:$C<>"", IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A)>1,"Not Unique","Unique")
    )
  )
}
```

How can I modify this formula to not flag the first instance of a non-unique row?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks very strange to me, perhaps try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($C$2:$C="","",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$100,A2:A100)=1,"Unique","Not Unique")))
```

Comment: The formula is just structured in such a way that it is easier to see what is happening. The "Unique" with a semicolon just sets that as the header and put everything else below it. And in my experience, using IFS is typically a much more concise and easy to understand format when using conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

It'll need a Row number helper column:

J1 `=ARRAYFORMULA(row(A:A))`

Then, the magic formula, where `10` is the column ID for the helper column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(VLOOKUP(A:A,A:J,10,false)=row(A:A),"Unique","Not Unique"))
```

The vlookup returns the first row number in the helper column where the value in `A:A` is found and compares it to the currently calculated row.